# Problemas com Modal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Em meu projeto eu tenho tipo uma galeria de imagens. Até agora eu faço o upload da imagem e ela é exibida na página sem problema algum.

Só que agora eu preciso que, ao clicar na imagem, me abra um modal com a imagem em um tamanho maior. Mas não consigo fazer isso de forma dinâmica, ou seja, ao dar clique em uma determinada imagem, apareça os outros dados dessa determinada imagem no modal. Porém, não consigo fazer esse modal abrir de forma dinâmica.

Preciso referenciar ele de forma que fique exclusivo pra determinada imagem, Será que alguem pode me ajudar ?

O que já tenho é isso:

## Galeria de Imagens

```
<!-- Portfolio Grid Section -->
<section id="portfolio" class="bg-light-gray">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <h2 class="section-heading">Portfolio</h2>
            <div class="line"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#portfolioModal" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                    <div class="portfolio-hover">
                        <div class="portfolio-hover-content"> <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i> </div>
                    </div>
                    <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Foto)" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
                </a>
                <div class="portfolio-caption">
                    <h4>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Titulo)</h4>
                    <p class="text-muted">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Descricao)</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

## Modal (que não está dentro do foreach)

```
<!-- Portfolio Modals -->
<!-- Use the modals below to showcase details about your portfolio projects! -->
<!-- Portfolio Modal 1 -->
<div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
        <div class="lr">
            <div class="rl"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <!-- Project Details Go Here -->
                    <h2>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Titulo)</h2>
                    <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Foto)" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
                    <p class="text-muted">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Descricao)</p>

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>Fechar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize um plugin para Lightbox, como o Lightbox for MVC:

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.mvc.LightBox/

[Veja exemplos de utilização aqui](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/).

Comment: Mas existe alguma forma, com o código que tenho e sem usar seu plugin, de referenciar a imagem no modal ?

Comment: @ÉrikThiago Tente primeiro fazer sem o código. Depois veja na documentação do plugin como customizar o modal.

Answer (score 2):

Eu montei este exemplo, usando Ajax.BeginForm, porem tive que alterar um pouco seu escopo, coloquei a imagem como fundo da de um button ( acredito que o layout nao seja o objetivo da sua pergunta )

Ira funcionar da maneira que você quer, quase nao mudei o codigo, porem eu acho que a solucao que o Cigano sugeriu excelente ( melhor que a minha )!!

Controller:

```
  public class Imagem
  {
     public int ID { get; set; }
     public string Foto { get; set; }
     public string Titulo { get; set; }
     public string Descricao { get; set; }
  }
  public class ModalController : Controller
  {
     public List<Imagem> Imagens = new List<Imagem>();

     public ModalController()
     {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
           Imagens.Add(new Imagem { ID = i, Descricao = "descr" + i.ToString(), Titulo = "titu" + i.ToString(), Foto = "foto" + i.ToString() });
        }
     }

     public ActionResult Index(int id = 0)
     {
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
           return PartialView("_Index", Imagens.First(_ => _.ID == id));
        }
        return View(Imagens);
     }
  }
```

Sua view:

```
  @model List<MVCApp.Controllers.Imagem>
  @using (Ajax.BeginForm(null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "replaceDiv", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnSuccess = "$('#portfolioModal').modal('show');" }))
  {
     foreach (var item in Model)
     {
        <button type="submit" name="ID" value="@item.ID" style="background-image: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Foto)">
           <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
              <div class="portfolio-caption">
                 <h4>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Titulo)</h4>
                 <p class="text-muted">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Descricao)</p>
              </div>
           </div>
        </button>
     }
  }

  <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
           <div class="lr">
              <div class="rl"> </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
           <div id="replaceDiv">
              <div class="progress">
                 <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="45" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%">
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

E é necessário criar uma partial view "_Index.cshtml" :

```
  @model MVCApp.Controllers.Imagem
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
        <div class="modal-body">
           <!-- Project Details Go Here -->
           <h2>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.Titulo)</h2>
           <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.Foto)" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
           <p class="text-muted">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.Descricao)</p>

           <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>Fechar</button>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Não esqueça de adicionar o arquivo :

```
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
```

Comment: Trabalhosa, mas pertinente caso o programador não queira usar o plugin que mencionei. +1.

Comment: Sim cigano, concordo contigo, mas nao custa nada passar outras alternativas, como eu disse no meu post, eu prefiro a sua sugestao, porem cada um tem sua preferencia